# Flink to Nifi the Magic Header was not present

Tags: apache-flink, apache-nifi

I am trying to use [this example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/examples/NiFiSourceTopologyExample.java) to connect Nifi to Flink:

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    SiteToSiteClientConfig clientConfig = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8090/nifi")
            .portName("Data for Flink")
            .requestBatchCount(5)
            .buildConfig();

    SourceFunction<NiFiDataPacket> nifiSource = new NiFiSource(clientConfig);
    DataStream<NiFiDataPacket> streamSource = env.addSource(nifiSource).setParallelism(2);

    DataStream<String> dataStream = streamSource.map(new MapFunction<NiFiDataPacket, String>() {
        @Override
        public String map(NiFiDataPacket value) throws Exception {
            return new String(value.getContent(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
    });

    dataStream.print();
    env.execute();
```

I am running Nifi as a standalone server with default properties, except these properties:

```
nifi.remote.input.host=localhost
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=8090
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
```

The call fails each time, with following log in Nifi:

```
[Site-to-Site Worker Thread-24] o.a.nifi.remote.SocketRemoteSiteListener 
Unable to communicate with remote instance null due to
org.apache.nifi.remote.exception.HandshakeException: Handshake 
with nifi://localhost:61680 failed because the Magic Header 
was not present; closing connection
```

Nifi version: 1.7.1, Flink version: 1.7.1

Comment: Seems you try to connect flink to nifi by http... And nifi listening raw nifi protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I tried both `transportProtocol(SiteToSiteTransportProtocol.RAW)` and `HTTP` with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the `nifi-toolkit` I removed the custom value of `nifi.remote.input.socket.port` and then added `transportProtocol(SiteToSiteTransportProtocol.HTTP)` to my `SiteToSiteClientConfig` and `http://localhost:8080/nifi` as the URL.

The reason why I changed the port in the first place is that without specifying the  protocol `HTTP` it will use `RAW` by default. 
And when using the `RAW` protocol from Flink side, the client cannot create `Transaction` and prints the following warning:

```
Unable to refresh Remote Group's peers due to Remote instance of NiFi 
is not configured to allow RAW Socket site-to-site communications
```

That's why I thought it was a port issue

So now with the default config of Nifi, this works as expected:

```
SiteToSiteClientConfig clientConfig = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8080/nifi")
            .portName("portNameAsInNifi")
            .transportProtocol(SiteToSiteTransportProtocol.HTTP)
            .requestBatchCount(1)
            .buildConfig();
```